# Treatment of final E's in loanwords to English

Tags: phonology, borrowing

Karaoke (from Japanese), simile (from Latin), tu quoque (Latin), apostrophe (Ancient Greek via Latin), machete (Spanish), and other loanwords with final E sounds all end up with an /i/ at the end.

That would be fair enough but somehow Italian loanwords get a different treatment. **Their** final E's end up as /eɪ/!

Can the difference in shifts be explained?

Answer (score 1):

I have different judgments on *tu quoque* and don't think I've ever heard [tu kwokwi] – I also have a different judgment on *karaoke* which I pronounce [karaoke], but I recognize that's not typical. You don't give any examples of Italian words, and the ones that come to mind (numerous food-related words like *al dente, latte, farfalle, mafalde* and artsy terms like *andante, finale, sotto voce*) are relatively recent or recherche ([e], not [i]). Older and more-established Italian words include *minestrone, fettucine, linguine* with [i], and of course often orthographic *e* is simply not pronounced in some words (*belvedere, trombone*). I think the high-vowel pronunciation of *tagliatelle, rotelle* is more standard in the US though I might use [e].
the ultimate sign of nativization or else Sicilian origin. If there is a tendency for Italian words to be pronounced with [e] compared to words from other languages, I think it is because Italian words are more recent, and there is a greater chance in the US of encountering an actual Italian pronunciation of the word to override the rule that orthographic *e* is not pronounced [e].